# vuejs sample app npm run dev not working throwing Error: Cannot find module 'node:url'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vuejs I am following the below steps to create my vue js app in the local system.

Step:

> npm init vue@latest

✔ Project name: … **VueDemo**
✔ Add TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Add JSX Support? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? … No / Yes
✔ Add Pinia for state management? … No / Yes
✔ Add Vitest for Unit testing? … No / Yes
✔ Add Cypress for both Unit and End-to-End testing? … No / Yes
✔ Add ESLint for code quality? … No / Yes
✔ Add Prettier for code formatting? … No / Yes

Scaffolding project in ./**VueDemo**
Done.

cd VueDemo
npm install
npm run dev

It's throwing the following error in the console:

> failed to load config from
> /Users/ashok/MyStudy/Vue/VueDemo/vite.config.js error when starting
> dev server: Error: Cannot find module 'node:url' Require stack:
>
> - /Users/ashok/MyStudy/Vue/VueDemo/vite.config.js
> - /Users/ashok/MyStudy/Vue/VueDemo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0fc8e132.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
>   at Object. (/Users/ashok/MyStudy/Vue/VueDemo/vite.config.js:31:23)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
>   at Object._require.extensions. [as .js] (file:///Users/ashok/MyStudy/Vue/VueDemo/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0fc8e132.js:63096:24)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "vuedemo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
    "vite": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:URL

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This means that you have Node version that is too old. Use up to date stable version, 16 or 18

Answer (score 3):

Just upgrade your node to the latest, remove `node_modules`, and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

**Try using:**

node version 18.12.1 or above and npm version 9.2.0 or above

**after that try:**

`npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I use npx for most of the cases to build, run etc..,
can you try this in your terminal
`npx vite`